# Adding a UIToolBar above a UITabBar - Logic Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to know the logic of how to write this code.

This is my problem.

When a user taps a button, I need to show a `UIToolBar` (with a few buttons on it) on the view. This `toolBar` should appear ONLY above the `UITabBarcontroller`.

The view is a `UIScrollView`, so if I hardcode the position of the `UIToolBar`, it will be displayed in the wrong position each time the user scrolls (Hope you understand what I am saying).

I did the following. I hard coded the position of the `UIToolBar` (so it will place above the tab bar), and added it to the `Window`. This sounds like a good solution as the `windows` size will not change at all instance.

But, I don't want to add this to a `Window`. So is there any other way I could solve this problem?

Comment: I am asking a new approach to solve this issue, so why do you need code :S

Answer (score 0):

I would add an additional `UIView` to the `window` so that it acts as a container for both the `UIScrollView` and `UIToolbar`. Then resize the scrollview so that it falls short of the toolbar.

You should be thinking of this as layers of views

Comment: What will the height of the UIVIew ? The positioning of the ToolBar depends on the height of this UiView, Could you demonstrate your approach with some code if possible ?

Comment: If you use Storyboard and drag out the TabBarController the UIView is setup for you. Simply add the scrollview and Toolbar into this view and then connect it up to your viewController. Then programatically remove the Toolbar and scale the scrollview as required. All the sizing you need is there for you in the storyboard view. You could do it programatically but this way is simpler.