# Using UIToolbar above UITabbar - is it possible?

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitoolbar

My question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350421/adding-a-uitoolbar-above-a-uitabbar-logic-issue), but not exactly answered there.

What I want to do, is to convert an existing navigation-based app with different `UIToolbars` at the bottom of the individual `UITableViews` into an app that has a `UITabbar` interface. One of the tabs shall show the same hierachy of UITableView data as the existing app (which displays some kind of hierarchical data), whereas the others will be assigned something else (say: Settings, Help, ...) that is of no concern here. The idea is to allow the user to quickly switch to the "Help"-Screen from whatever stage of the navigation stack - and back.

For example, using 3 Tabs:

```
 1. Database root (UIToolbar) - folder 1 (UIToolbar) - file 1.1
                                                     - file 1.2
                              - folder 2 (UIToolbar) - file 2.1
                                                     - file 2.2
 2. Help (no UIToolbar)
 3. Settings (no UIToolbar)
```

I have never seen such a design in any existing app, although [the question cited above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350421/adding-a-uitoolbar-above-a-uitabbar-logic-issue) suggests that it might in fact be possible to keep the existing UIToolbars from the old app and simply place them above the tab bar.

Is this

- technically possible (without problems e.g. with device rotation)?
- allowed by Interface guidelines?

Although sample code would be appreciated, I mostly would like to find out whether it is worth trying to build an app like this - or whether such a design is a bad idea in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it out, and now I can answer my own question:

- It's possible, and there are no problems with device rotation, if you make sure that the views for every single tab can rotate.
- Although it looks a bit unusual, I find it very usable. Of course, it costs some vertical space.

As for the implementation, I found it to be surprisingly simple:
All I had to do was to use Interface Builder to insert a `UITabBarController` in place of my original main `UIViewController` and move the latter to the first tab of the former. Then create some more tabs with `UIViewControllers` inside and rename their classes to those of my other existing `UIViewControllers`. Finally set the associated NIB-Files for all these controllers manually in the relevant interface builder inspector pane (because they are now no longer instantiated by my code) and change one single line of code to make the `UITabBarController` the `root` controller.

Result: the `UIToolbar` appears above the `UITabbar` for the first tab, but not for the others. Its position is fixed (when scrolling a list or similar), but it autorotates together with the tab bar and everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a UITabBar anywhere, you just won't be using its controller.  You will have to write your own controller and handle what happens during device rotation (or use iOS 6's auto layout features).